# How to use loop to SUM categories?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use a loop with vba to sum values from one worksheet to another. I am struggling with writing my code to match values from `Sheet 4` and if the value matches then sum the categories from `Sheet 1`, if not then skip to the next office. I would also like to exclude certain categories from being included in the SUM loop for example, exclude "Book". Currently my macro is writing to `Sheet3`. Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, dic As Object
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dic.CompareMode = 1
    a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .CompareMode = 1
        For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
            If Not dic.Exists(a(i, 1)) Then dic(a(i, 2)) = dic.Count + 2
            If Not .Exists(a(i, 1)) Then
                Set .Item(a(i, 1)) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                .Item(a(i, 1)).CompareMode = 1
            End If
            .Item(a(i, 1))(a(i, 2)) = .Item(a(i, 1))(a(i, 2)) + a(i, 3)
        Next
        ReDim a(1 To .Count + 1, 1 To dic.Count + 1)
        a(1, 1) = Sheets("sheet1").[a1]
        For i = 0 To dic.Count - 1
            a(1, i + 2) = dic.Keys()(i)
        Next
        For i = 0 To .Count - 1
            a(i + 2, 1) = .Keys()(i)
            For ii = 2 To UBound(a, 2)
                a(i + 2, ii) = .items()(i)(a(1, ii)) + 0
            Next
        Next
    End With
    With Sheets("sheet3").Cells(1).Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2))
        .EntireColumn.ClearContents
        Sheets("sheet1").[a1].Copy .Rows(1)
        .Value = a: .Columns.AutoFit: .Parent.Activate
    End With
End Sub
```

This is how the data looks

[image]

and this is the output that is desired

[image]

Comment: If I have understood you correctly then you do not need VBA for this. A simple Pivot can help you out?

Comment: @Siddharth Rout Unfortunately I cannot use a pivot table for what I am trying to accomplish. I would need and prefer to use VBA

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your data and how the output should look like?

Comment: @SiddharthRout created links to the images, cant actually post them on here yet

Comment: upload them to any free file uploading site and share the link here. I will upload it for you

Comment: @SiddharthRout i edited my post with two dropbox links

Answer (score 0):

In this example, we will use arrays to achieve what you want. I have commented the code so that you shall not have a problem understanding it. However if you still do then simply ask :)

**Input**

[image]

**Output**

[image]

**Logic**

1. Find last row and last column of input sheet
2. Store in an array
3. Get unique names from Column A and Row 1
4. Define output array
5. Compare array to store sum
6. Create new sheet and output to that sheet

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, wsNew As Worksheet
    Dim tempArray As Variant, OutputAr() As Variant
    Dim officeCol As New Collection
    Dim productCol As New Collection
    Dim itm As Variant
    Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long, totalsum As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long

    '~~> Input sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1

    With ws
        '~~> Get Last Row and last column
        lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        lcol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        '~~> Store it in a temp array
        tempArray = .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lrow, lcol)).Value

        '~~> Create a unique collection using On error resume next
        On Error Resume Next
        For i = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
            officeCol.Add tempArray(i, 1), CStr(tempArray(i, 1))
            productCol.Add tempArray(i, 2), CStr(tempArray(i, 2))
        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    '~~> Define you new array which will hold the desired output
    ReDim OutputAr(1 To officeCol.Count + 1, 1 To productCol.Count + 1)

    '~~> Store the rows and columns in the array
    i = 2
    For Each itm In officeCol
        OutputAr(i, 1) = itm
        i = i + 1
    Next itm
    i = 2
    For Each itm In productCol
        OutputAr(1, i) = itm
        i = i + 1
    Next itm

    '~~> Calculate sum by comparing the arrays
    For i = 2 To officeCol.Count + 1
        For j = 2 To productCol.Count + 1
            totalsum = 0
            For k = LBound(tempArray) To UBound(tempArray)
                If OutputAr(i, 1) = tempArray(k, 1) And _
                   OutputAr(1, j) = tempArray(k, 2) Then
                   totalsum = totalsum + tempArray(k, 3)
                End If
            Next k

            OutputAr(i, j) = totalsum
        Next j
    Next i

    '~~> Create a new sheet
    Set wsNew = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add

    '~~> Outout the array
    wsNew.Range("A1").Resize(officeCol.Count + 1, productCol.Count + 1).Value = OutputAr
End Sub
```

Comment: the output was Sheet4 which is different, here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/izkvg8h2dgfe8yj/Capture2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: if your output sheet is predefined then you do not need vba. You can simply use formulas

Comment: If you put a formula `=SUMIFS(Sheet1!C:C,Sheet1!A:A,A2,Sheet1!B:B,B1)` in cell B2, you will get 42 :)

Comment: long story short, I'm downloading a WB file from our company site that has the data sheet. I'm opening that downloaded file using VBA, and copying values with the loop. The file changes every day, and cannot be connected to

Comment: Then all you have to do is change the last 2 lines of the code to match the output array with Col A and Row1 of Output sheet and then fill across. Would you like to give it a try?